# Correct way of making POST request with JSON in SPRING MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, rest

I am fairly new to spring and want to the correct way of making post request. I have a list of json object that I want to post to my server
for example

```
var list = [{name:"abc",age:23},{name:"xyz",age:22},{name:"xcx",age:33}]
```

I am making a post request in google closure using xhr to my server in this fashion

```
 model.xhrPost(id,url,"list="+JSON.stringify(this.list),callback);
```

This is what my controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/getInput"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String logClientError(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        try{
            String errorObj = request.getParameter("list");
            JSONArray errors = new JSONArray(errorObj);
            some more code here which loops through the list...

            result.put("isSuccess", true);
            return result.toString();
        }catch(JSONException e){
            result.put("isSuccess", false);
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

So in short I am making a post request by passing querystring parameter. Is this the correct way or should the content be posted in the body? If I post in the body what changes do I have to make ?

Comment: yes thanks. It did give me an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not how you should post the data to REST endpoint. Going this way you can use GET instead of POST and it will work as well. However POST should be definitely used to create new resource and the content should be carried in message body not as a query param.

On the backend side you can catch and parse the content yourself or create a class (see below) that will be filled with data from body.

DTO:

```
class Person {
    String name
    Integer age
}

class PersonList {
    List<Person> persons
}
```

Endpoint:

```
public String logClientError(@RequestBody PersonList list, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
```

Body:

```
{ 
   "persons": [{name:"abc",age:23},{name:"xyz",age:22},{name:"xcx",age:33}] 
}
```

`@ResponseBody` can be used in the same manner for responses.